# Plural names in name-name construction

Tags: plural-forms, nouns, compounds

Suppose that you have a group of items and you make a hierarchy structure for them. Now, you call this structure, "item hierarchy" or "items hierarchy"?

However, my real phrase is "context hierarchy" vs. "contexts hierarchy"

In general there are some noun-noun constructions which address a group of things. Then the first noun is plural or singular?

Comment: Although this question is not exactly a duplicate of the question JMB links to, the first sentence in that question can be considered a good answer to this question. So I agree with voting this question as a possible duplicate.

Comment: Read Jay's answer in the link carefully, especially the part about "...*of* X".  *Context hierarchy* is ambiguous: does it mean hierarchy *within* the context, or hierarchy of contexts? Even if it appears to be a concise alternative, using nouns as modifiers isn't always the clearest approach.

Comment: @TRomano I did, I asked you a different question in another post, why I got this response here!

Comment: @TRomano its *hierarchy of contexts*, then you suggest to use this exact phrase?

Comment: @Admad: if you're referring to *nested* contexts (each context can contain one or more sub-contexts, which in turn can contain one or more sub-sub-contents,, which in turn can  contain ... to an arbitrary depth of recursion)  "recursive context hierarchy" might be clearest or "hierarchy of recursive contexts".